# Usage of h:outputlabel vs label

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.1

In JSF 1.1 (unfortunately I'm semi-stuck using legacy infrastructure) what is the advantage (or indeed purpose) of using `<h:outputlabel>` when I could just use a standard `<label>` tag in a form?

I get the feeling it might be related to the dynamic field ID/names produced by jsf, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that many of the attributes of `<h:outputLabel/>` can use EL expressions.

Comment: That depends on the view technology though. In JSP you indeed can't use EL in template text, but in Facelets you can. However, with something legacy as JSF 1.1 I wouldn't expect to see Facelets :)